# Optimize COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table `items` from which I'm selecting 40 rows at a time ordered by the `popularity` of the item.

The `popularity` score is simply `downloads/impressions`;

**Query**:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM items
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downloads WHERE item = items.id)/
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM impressions WHERE item = items.id)
 LIMIT 40;
```

The problem is that the query takes forever to complete (ranging from 2 to 10 seconds).

At the moment we have 25K items, 18M impressions, and 560k download.

We already tried adding the fields `downloads` and `impressions` in the table `items` and keeping the count updated using triggers (after an insert in the tables `impressions` and `downloads` we increment the values), but we've had some issues with deadlocking.

Is there a better way to optimize this query?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here's the output of EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type           table             type      possible_keys   key       key_len   ref                 rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY               items             ALL       NULL            NULL      NULL      NULL                20496   Using filesort
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    impressions       ref       PRIMARY         PRIMARY   4         db.items.id         74      Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    downloads         ref       PRIMARY         PRIMARY   4         db.items.id         274     Using index
```

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(35) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24369 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE `impressions` (
  `item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item`,`user`),
  CONSTRAINT `impression_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE `downloads` (
  `item` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user` char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item`,`user`),
  CONSTRAINT `download_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct.  There is no table called `items` in the query.  Your table definitions are also not correct, referring to columns not in the table.

Comment: Yep; that's not your query

Comment: You can try with some Materialized View. Here there is a description similar to your issue: https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah, sorry... fixed it now

Comment: @NicolaLepetit yeah, there is one drawback with that approach: for new items, the score would be zero for a relatively long time. Plus, the time to update the "count" table would be quite long, wouldn't that block the whole table, thus blocking the main query for a couple of minutes?

Comment: @guidev. I am more into PostegrSQL tham MySQL. You can use the CONCURRENTLY Switch, to solve the problem: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html. Basically you create a parallel view and, when it is ready you switch to the updated one.

Comment: I've just re-read your request. "it takes forever to complete" and "ranging from 2 to 10 seconds"? I don't consider this slow at all. You are grouping and aggregating all rows in two tables, then join them, then sort and rank them, then join them again. This takes time of course. What you are looking for hence would be a data warehouse with pre-aggregated data.

Answer (score 1):

I think next query can resolve your problem:

```
SELECT 
    item,items.name, downloads.cnt/impressions.cnt AS rate  
FROM  (
    SELECT item, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM downloads GROUP BY item
) AS downloads
JOIN (
    SELECT item, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM impressions GROUP BY item
) impressions
JOIN items ON items.id = downloads.items
ORDER BY rate DESC 
LIMIT 40;
```

Also care about `downloads` and `impressions` tables have indexed by item field.

Comment: @guidev - What version of MySQL?  There was a significant improvement at some point when `JOINing` two derived tables.

Answer (score 1):

Not solvable with that approach.

There are two solutions:

- Keep counters (by `item.id`) for impressions and downloads.
- Summary tables.

**Counters**  This involves adding an extra column for each counter to the `items` table.  Or building a parallel table with `id` and the various counters.  For really high volumn of counts, the latter avoids some clashes between various queries.

**Summary Tables**  Build and incrementally augment a table(s) that summarize counts like these, plus perhaps other `SUMs`, `COUNTs`, etc.  The table would perhaps be augmented daily for the previous day's information.  Then the "sum the counts" to get the grand total; this will be much faster than your current query.

More on Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Answer (score 0):

I'd count downloads and impressions first and then get the top 40:

```
with d as (select item, count(*) as total from downloads group by item)
   , i as (select item, count(*) as total from impressions group by item)
   , top40 as select item from d join i using (item) order by d.total / i.total limit 40)
select *
from items
where id in
(
  select item from top40
);
```

The `WITH` clause is available as of MySQL 8. In earlier versions, you'd work with subqueries instead.

As `item` is a foreign key in `downloads` and `impressions` and `id` is the primary key in `items`, I suppose there is an index on them. Otherwise create one:

```
create unique index idx1 on items(id);
create index idx2 on downloads(item);
create index idx3 on impressions(item);
```

Comment: Well, now that I look at it, my answer isn't so very different from Slava Rozhnev's and you say that their approach is still too slow. In that case you may want to follow the data warehouse approach suggested by Rick James.

Comment: Presumably `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence obviating `UNIQUE(id)`.